# Shared SecurityContextHolder across multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

**Context:** I'm writing a web app that is meant to serve two different API's, each with their own authentication filter. Both filters process and authenticate JWT tokens, however the tokens themselves contain different payloads and come from different authentication sources. Also, even though the tokens are different, and come from different sources, they share the same credentials for logging in, and are secured using the same key.

Ie: You could go to either one of these auth urls, with the same credentials and get back a different JWT token, with entirely different payloads.

/auth/auth1/login
/auth/auth2/login

**Problem:** The problem I am encountering is that if I authenticate to one of them, I have access to the other. Even without providing a token.

Meaning if I go to /requests/something, authenticate using a bearer token from auth provider 1, then go to /ims/oneroster/v1p1/somethingElse (without passing in a different token from auth provider 2) I am able to access data, even though I haven't authenticated using the filter associated with that path.

At the moment, the only way I know of to make sure that each filter is correctly checking if the user's token is valid is to put **SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();** at the top of each of the filters doFilterInternal method. However, I'm pretty sure I shouldn't be doing that.

Can anyone see a problem with what I have below, or make some recommendations?

**SecurityConfig.class**

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    //https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#multiple-httpsecurity

    @Configuration @Order(1)
    public static class XPressWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        private final CacheService cacheService;

        public XPressWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter(CacheService cacheService) {this.cacheService = cacheService;}

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/requests/**")
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                        .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManagerBean(), cacheService))
                            //.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint())
            ;
        }
    }

    @Configuration @Order(2)
    public static class OneRosterWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        private final CacheService cacheService;

        public OneRosterWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter(CacheService cacheService) {this.cacheService = cacheService;}

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/ims/oneroster/v1p1/**")
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and().addFilter(new OneRosterAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManagerBean(), cacheService))
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

**OneRosterAuthorizationFilter.class**

```java
public class OneRosterAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
    private final CacheService cacheService;

    public OneRosterAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager, CacheService cacheService) {
        super(authManager);
        this.cacheService = cacheService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.debug("GOING TO ONEROSTER FILTER");

        AuthRequest authRequest = new AuthRequest(req);
        if(authRequest.isAuthEnabled()) {
            if(authRequest.isHeader() || (authRequest.isParameter() && authRequest.isAllowTokenParameter())) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req, authRequest);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, AuthRequest authRequest) {
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(authRequest.getToken())) {
            return null;  //Token was blank... 403 Forbidden
        }

        DecodedToken decodedToken = TokenDecoder.decodeToken(authRequest.getToken());

        Application application = null;
        if(decodedToken != null) {
            application = new Application(decodedToken.getAppId(), decodedToken.getToken(), cacheService);
        }

        try {
                if(!System.getenv("provider_id").equalsIgnoreCase(decodedToken.getProviderId())) {
                    throw new JWTVerificationException("Provider Ids Don't Match....");
                }

                if(application != null && StringUtils.isNotBlank(application.getApp().getProviderSecret())) {
                JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC256(application.getApp().getProviderSecret().getBytes()))
                        .withIssuer(PropertiesLoader.getInstance().getProperty("security.auth.jwt.issuer"))
                        .build().verify(authRequest.getToken());
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(application, decodedToken.getToken(), getACLs(application));
            }
        }
        catch (JWTVerificationException exception) {
            //https://medium.com/fullstackblog/spring-security-jwt-token-expired-custom-response-b85437914b81
            req.setAttribute("JWTVerificationException", exception.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return null; //DecodedToken or Application was null... 403 Forbidden
    }


    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> getACLs(Application application) {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        application.getPermissions().forEach(pathPermission -> {
            if(pathPermission.getGet()) {
                grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("get:" + pathPermission.getPath()));
            }
            if(pathPermission.getPost()) {
                grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("post:" + pathPermission.getPath()));
            }
            if(pathPermission.getPut()) {
                grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("put:" + pathPermission.getPath()));
            }
            if(pathPermission.getDelete()) {
                grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("delete:" + pathPermission.getPath()));
            }
        });
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }
}
```

**JWTAuthorizationFilter.class**

```java
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
    private final CacheService cacheService;

    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager, CacheService cacheService) {
        super(authManager);
        this.cacheService = cacheService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.debug("GOING TO JWT FILTER");

        AuthRequest authRequest = new AuthRequest(req);
        if(authRequest.isAuthEnabled()) {
            if(authRequest.isHeader() || (authRequest.isParameter() && authRequest.isAllowTokenParameter())) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req, authRequest);
                if(authentication != null) {
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                }
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, AuthRequest authRequest) {
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(authRequest.getToken())) {
            return null;  //Token was blank... 403 Forbidden
        }

        DecodedToken decodedToken = TokenDecoder.decodeToken(authRequest.getToken());

        Application application = null;
        if(decodedToken != null) {
            application = new Application(decodedToken.getApplication_id(), decodedToken.getToken(), cacheService);
        }

        try {
            if(application != null && StringUtils.isNotBlank(application.getApp().getProviderSecret())) {
                JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC256(application.getApp().getProviderSecret().getBytes()))
                        .withIssuer(PropertiesLoader.getInstance().getProperty("security.auth.jwt.issuer"))
                        .build().verify(authRequest.getToken());
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(application, decodedToken.getToken(), getACLs(application));
            }
        }
        catch (JWTVerificationException exception) {
            //https://medium.com/fullstackblog/spring-security-jwt-token-expired-custom-response-b85437914b81
            req.setAttribute("JWTVerificationException", exception.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return null; //DecodedToken or Application was null... 403 Forbidden
    }


    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> getACLs(Application application) {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        application.getPermissions().forEach(pathPermission -> {
            if(pathPermission.getGet()) {
                grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("get:" + pathPermission.getPath()));
            }
            if(pathPermission.getPost()) {
                grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("post:" + pathPermission.getPath()));
            }
            if(pathPermission.getPut()) {
                grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("put:" + pathPermission.getPath()));
            }
            if(pathPermission.getDelete()) {
                grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("delete:" + pathPermission.getPath()));
            }
        });
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }
}
```

```
Note: Application is the class that implements UserDetails
```

Comment: Do you need a HTTP session? If your services are stateless, you don't have that kind of problem.

Comment: At the moment I don't believe I need the session. But assuming I do in the future how difficult would it be to make that happen? Also, if I can have it stateless, how would I go about fixes the current issue? Thanks.

Comment: To make it stateless you have to change the session policy, see [SessionCreationPolicy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/http/SessionCreationPolicy.html#STATELESS). You also have to be sure, that your application doesn't open by itself (your code).

Comment: Best way to use a session is to split your application into two applications (running in the same container or in two different containers).

Comment: Thanks @dur. I think I'll try going the stateless approach for now, and if it turns out I need the session I'll split them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a comment from dur, here is the resolution to my problem. All I needed to do was add:

```
.and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

to each of the HttpSecurity objects.

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    //https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#multiple-httpsecurity

    @Configuration @Order(1)
    public static class XPressWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        private final CacheService cacheService;

        public XPressWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter(CacheService cacheService) {this.cacheService = cacheService;}

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            //https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/
            http.antMatcher("/requests/**")
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and().addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManagerBean(), cacheService))
                        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                    .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        }
    }

    @Configuration @Order(2)
    public static class OneRosterWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        private final CacheService cacheService;

        public OneRosterWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter(CacheService cacheService) {this.cacheService = cacheService;}

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/ims/oneroster/v1p1/**")
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and().addFilter(new OneRosterAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManagerBean(), cacheService))
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        }
    }
}
```